# retrieve data from firebase firestore inside of GridView using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

the problem is that I can not Map data from firestore firebase inside "children" of GridView.count.
I want to Map a specific document from firebase inside of GridView.count.
Please Help me.

productSnap.data.map((document)  please help me how to correct this
and I am facing this error when I use my code.

```
Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method 'map'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => ProductCard)
```

ProductCard is the name of the widget in this code....
[image]

```
                         FutureBuilder(
                              future: _firebaseServices.productsRef
                                  .doc(document.id)
                                  .get(),
                              builder: (context, productSnap) {
                                if (productSnap.hasError) {
                                  return Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text("${productSnap.error}"),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }

                                if (productSnap.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.done) {
         
                                  return GridView.count(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      childAspectRatio: .53,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 10.0,
                                          bottom: 12.0,
                                          left: 5,
                                          right: 5),
                                      children:
                  /////////////////  the problem is in here  ///////////////
                                          productSnap.data.map((document) {
                             
                                        return ProductCard(
                                          title: document['name'],
                                       );
                                      }).toList());
                                }

                                return Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use querysnapshot here not document, update your future to:-

```
future:_firebaseServices.productsRef.get(),
builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> productSnap) {
```

And gridview children as :-

```
// ...
    children: List.generate(productSnap.data!.docs.length,(index){
             var document= productSnap.data!.docs[index];
             return ProductCard(
                title: document['name'],
            );
    })
```

Comment: no. here i want to retrieve from a specific document

Comment: But your document don't have any array for products

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to do it with the help of Deepak Lohmod. I also added "id" field in my Products. id is equal to the document uid of Product.

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _firebaseServices.productsRef
          .where("id", isEqualTo: document.id)
          .get(),
      builder: (context, productSnap) {
        if (productSnap.hasError) {
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("${productSnap.error}"),
            ),
          );
        }

        if (productSnap.connectionState ==
            ConnectionState.done) {

          return GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              childAspectRatio: .53,
              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10.0,
                  bottom: 12.0,
                  left: 5,
                  right: 5),
              children: productSnap.data.docs
                  .map<Widget>((document) {
                final dynamic data = document.data();
 
                return ProductCard(
                  title: data['name'],


                );
              }).toList());
        }

        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      });
```